# Is SOCP harder than GP?

Tags: soft-question, convex-optimization, numerical-optimization, second-order-cone-programming, geometric-programming

As an electrical engineer, I have been studying convex optimization for a while. During my study, I see that most textbooks claim that both [second-order cone programs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second-order_cone_programming) (SOCP) and [geometric programs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_programming) (GP) can be solved effectively with a modern solver. However, I cannot find any document that compares them. Hence, is SOCP harder than GP. Furthermore, is there anyway to come up with a Big O complexity to measure the difficulty of solving them in terms of the number of variables and constraints?

Comment: Aren't you conflating problems and algorithms?

Comment: Oh my bad for not being clear enough. What I really want to said is on the problem aspect. As they are both non linear problem, I dont know which problem is harder ?

Comment: A problem is a collection of instances. There are different algorithms for LP, for example, and they don't have the same worst-case complexity